# About the existence of harmonic conjugate

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

I am reading Donald Sarason's "Notes on Complex Function Theory".
I have two questions about the following (taken from page $88$ of
the book):

[image]

1. Why did we had to use $g$ ? We already had $f$ which was claimed
   to be holomorphic, so it seems that$-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$
   is the harmonic conjugate of $u$
2. I'm guessing I am wrong in my statement that $-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$
   is the harmonic conjugate of $u$, what is the harmonic conjugate
   ?

Comment: Look at the definition of $f$ again. $-\partial u/\partial y$ is the harmonic conjugate of $\partial u/\partial x$, not $u$.

Comment: If $u$ is a harmonic function then there is a holomorphic function of the form $u+iv$, where $v$ is unique up to a constant. We call $v$ the harmonic conjugate. Why would we think $-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$ is a harmonic conjugate of $u$, i.e. why believe $u-i\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$ is a holomorphic function of $x+iy$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why did we had to use $g$

Because we want to prove the theorem stated above. The existence of $g$ with $\operatorname{Re}g=u$ is a part of the theorem.

> it seems that $−\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}$ is the harmonic conjugate of $u$

This is incorrect, as Potato and anon already pointed out.

> what is the harmonic conjugate of $u$?

Since $\operatorname{Re}g=u$, the function $\operatorname{Im}g$ is a harmonic conjugate of $u$. (Not *the* harmonic conjugate, since we can add any constant and get other conjugate functions.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can I conclude that $u+c$ is $Im(g)$ (which is a harmonic conjugate) ? (where $c$ is a constant)

Comment: @Belgi What would be the basis for such conclusion? Is there a theorem that the imaginary part of a holomorphic function is equal to its real part, plus a constant?

Comment: No. My reasoning is this: We had $\frac{\partial u_{1}}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$
and we concluded $u-u_{1}=c$ for some constant $c$, but since we
assumed $g(z_{0})=u(z_{0})$ we got that $u=u_{1}$. So we got that
the real part of $g$ is $u$. Now I'm looking at the imaginary part,
we got: $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial u_{1}}{\partial y}$,
doesn't this equality means that $u$ {[}lus a constant is the imaginary
part of $g$ ?

Comment: @Belgi Are you misreading $v_1$ as $u_1$, by any chance? The imaginary part of $g$ is denoted $v_1$ in the proof.

Comment: But they used C-R equations to express the imaginary part of $g$ using $u_1$, in the first line that have $g'=..=..$

Comment: What are your thoughts ?